# By using QOpenGLContext and OpenGLVertexBufferObject, rendering looks missed depth

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, opengl

My platform information: Qt 5.4.1, ubuntu 14.04, windows 8.1

I have made QOpenGLWindow based on QWindow. To make it OpenGLWindow, I used QOpenGLContext and made OpenGL context for each of them. In QOpenGLWindow, to render object I used VertexBufferObject of native OpenGL. and I passed vertices, normals to buffer object and rendered it. here is my two situation of this application. first one worked on ubuntu 14.04, second one worked on windows 8.1.

[image]

[image]

I have got first one because I develop application mainly on ubuntu 14.04.  It seems that it doesn't know depth when it is rendered. and it looks transparent for all front faces. I had hard time to figure out problem so I tested it on windows 8.1 with same version of Qt which is Qt 5.4.1. It works fine as you can see second picture.
So I'm thinking about Qt's issue for different platform. I had similar issue before(it was fixed to Qt 5.5): https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-45037

is there anyone with similar problem?

Comment: I think it is nearly impossible to give here an answer without seeing the code. Something may be unitialized and is fixed by some driver related stuff. You should remember that this is a site to get help regarding a problem and not to post a simple bug report.

Comment: You need to adjust the driver settings of your Nvidia or Ati graphics card. Try to set the high Quality or prefer quality in the driver control pannel.